# Angular: Call Modal in different file

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which can be called from different pages. So, I need that in different HTML and JS files.

fileA.html and fileA.js are main while fileB.html and fileB.js have the modal. 
When I am trying to call it I am getting error.

fileA.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click='openModal()' ><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Modal</button>
```

fileA.js

```
angular.module('query').controller('Modal2Ctrl', function ( .... ){
$scope.openModal = function (){

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/#/data/modal/modal1.html',
        windowClass: 'modal',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            object : $scope.qid,
        }
    });
 };
 }
```

fileB.html:

```
<div ng-controller=""> or <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <!-- Modal Footer -->
```

fileB.js

```
angular.module('export').controller('Modal1Ctrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $log, $compile, $timeout, $modalInstance, ...){ ... }
```

I would like to use fileB.html and fileB.js on different pages. 
Any advice on how to call the modal?

Comment: Man, you made this WAAAY more complicated than it has to be. Why not put the modal into a directive that is hidden behind an `ng-if`?

Comment: Move the code for opening the dialog box in a service, and inject that service in the controllers that require it..

Comment: @Pytth for ng-if to work, the modal has to be on the same HTML right? I am not sure how to do for a different HTHML file. Do you mean to say use ng-include?

Comment: @maddog No, you could create a directive that has its own HTML template along with it. So far as I am aware, this directive should work anywhere so long as it is not part of another directive's html template. By that I mean, it would work in directives such as `ng-if` or `ng-repeat` because they themselves are `decorator` directives and do not have their own html.

Comment: Thanks @TechMa9iac. I got stuck with some other stuffs so did not update it here. Modal Service worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service
Thanks to @ TechMa9iac for the advice.